# How to get XML node name in Mule using MEL or XPATH expression

Tags: xml, xpath, mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I have a simple requirement... I have an xml file :-

```
<Service>
<Name>Abcd</Name>
<Age>28</Age>
</Service>
```

Now my requirement is to display a node name using XPATH or MEL ...
So far I tried with various XPATH expression like the following :-

```
<flow name="Flow1WManager" doc:name="newFlow">
   <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="File_Input" doc:name="File"  path="E:\backup\test">
       <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="aa.xml" caseSensitive="false"/>
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
<logger message="NodeName1 : #[xpath-node://Service/*[1]/node()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
<logger message="NodeName2 : #[xpath-node://.[xpath:local-name()='Service']/*/node()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
<logger message="NodeName3 : #[xpath-node://.[xpath:local-name()='Service']/.[xpath:local-name()]/node()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
```

But I am getting following in console :-

```
INFO  2014-08-14 23:03:28,915 [[XPATHWithLocal-name].Flow1WManager.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: NodeName1 : org.dom4j.tree.DefaultText@5fffd6fd [Text: "Abcd"]
INFO  2014-08-14 23:03:28,921 [[XPATHWithLocal-name].Flow1WManager.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: NodeName2 : [org.dom4j.tree.DefaultText@5fffd6fd [Text: "Abcd"], org.dom4j.tree.DefaultText@1bb3db1b [Text: "28"]]
INFO  2014-08-14 23:03:28,923 [[XPATHWithLocal-name].Flow1WManager.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: NodeName3 : [org.dom4j.tree.DefaultText@1a1b4f86 [Text: "
"], org.dom4j.tree.DefaultDocument@1123b146 [Document: name null], org.dom4j.tree.DefaultText@157bad48 [Text: "
"], org.dom4j.tree.DefaultDocument@3e4b7374 [Document: name null], org.dom4j.tree.DefaultText@3cf5d7d2 [Text: "
"]]
```

I have used `local-name XPath function` .. but unable to get the Node Name .. am I missing something .. Please help

Comment: Uuse MEL instead of the old and deprecated `xpath-node` expression resolver, see: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Reference#MuleExpressionLanguageReference-Xpath This will make it easier to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple Xpath statement

Service-`#[xpath('xpath:name(/*)')]`
Name-`#[xpath('xpath:name(/Service/Name)')]`
Age-`#[xpath('xpath:name(/Service/Age)')]`

If you dont know the node name
Name-`xpath('xpath:name(/Service/*[1])')`
Age-`xpath('xpath:name(/Service/*[2])')`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this below code. It's working.

```
NAME =====>  #[xpath3('//Service/Name')]
AGE -======> #[xpath3('//Service/Age')]
```

Comment: The time I posted this question, XPATH3 was not in the picture and I was using Mule version 3.3 ... anyway it's resolved long back .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

XML EXAMPLE PAYLOAD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <field type="0" name="visit">TEST</field>
    <field type="0" name="latitude">1.23</field>
    <field type="0" name="longitude">1.23</field>
    <field type="0" name="comments">TEST</field>
</response>
```

MEL xpath3:

```
#[xpath3('/response/field[@name=\'visit\']',payload, 'STRING')]
```

try this

```
FOR NAME:
#[xpath3('/Service/Name',payload, 'STRING')] 
FOR AGE:
#[xpath3('/Service/Age',payload, 'NUMBER')]
```

Arguments
xpath3(0,1,2)

0: XPath expression.

1: input document.

2: output option: BOOLEAN, STRING, NUMBER, NODESET, NODE or {} this always return a List of Strings